# How to set content of html dynamically which is already using *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, httpclient

I've created html component which is using `*ngFor` to create html element dynamically. 
 which creates total 3 `<p></p>` tags on running. `<br>` I have provide data like subject in the component file which gets populated dynamically but marks property is being requested from server, which I'm not able to set it in html.

**HTML**

```
<div class="home_social">
  <p *ngFor="let item of homeItems"> Subject: {{item.subject}}" Marks:{{item.marks}}"</p>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
homeItems = [
    {subject: 'Maths', marks: this.home.maths},
    {subject: 'Science', marks: this.home.science'},
    {subject: 'English', marks: this.home.english}
  ];

  showHomeResource() {
    this.appService.getHomeResource().subscribe((data: Home) => this.home = data);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showHomeResource();
  }
```

Updating marks in this way gives error cause this.home.maths is being invoked before initialisation. Home object is initialized in showHomeResource() after requesting the server.

Either we can try to update marks in component file without getting this error or we can try directly accessing the home object in html file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: <div class="home_social">
  <p *ngFor="let item of (homeItems| async)">
 Subject: {{item?.subject}} Marks:{{item?.marks}}</p>
</div>

Comment: Yes but this gives error cause marks is invoking home object before initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, if i understand the mistake, we have a problem:

```
 homeItems = [
    {subject: 'Maths', marks: this.home.maths},//here this.home.math is asynchronous
    {subject: 'Science', marks: this.home.science'},
    {subject: 'English', marks: this.home.english}
  ];
```

in angular you can manage this asynchronous stream of data with the observables and rxjs. obviously this is not the only way to get the things working, but, for me is the more comfortable. so i presume you have a component like this

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{ 
  homeItems = [
      {subject: 'Maths', marks: this.home.maths},
      {subject: 'Science', marks: this.home.science},
      {subject: 'English', marks: this.home.english}
  ];
  home: any;
  
  constructor(
    
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getHomeResource().subscribe((data: Home) => this.home = data);
  }

  showHomeResource() {
    this.appService.getHomeResource().subscribe((data: Home) => this.home = 
    data);
  } 
}
```

your problem is that you are tryng to access to home, when you initialize homeItems, but home is undefained at that moment.a way to do this with rxjs is:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{ 
  
  homeItems$ = new Observable(); //we can transform homeItems$ in an observable, the $ is a convention
  home: any;
  
  constructor(
    
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.homeItems$ = this.appService.getHomeResource().pipe(
      map((data: Home) => { //tha map method is like the array.map of js, but are you mapping your data!
        this.home = data 
        return  [
          {subject: 'Maths', marks: this.home.maths },      //here we can assign to the homeItems$  marks our value. the trick is that in this moment we are not rendering the view, check the html file to understand
          {subject: 'Science',  marks: this.home.science},
          {subject: 'English',  marks: this.home.english}
      ];
      })
  }

}
```

if you see we are not subscribing in the controller. beacause we can do in a clear way in the html file.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="homeItems$ | async; let homeItems"> <!-- here we subscribing the observable and we assign the value in homeItems -->
  <div class="home_social">
    <p *ngFor="let item of homeItems"> Subject: {{item.subject}}" Marks:{{item.marks}}"</p> <!-- here we are sure that we have data -->
  </div>
</ng-container>
```